# Font with its name displayed in different font

Tags: font-forge, ttf

When looking in Microsoft Word, some fonts, such as [Wingdings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingdings), are shown in the dropdown using a different font for the font's name, so that you can actually read it.

[image]

I have designed a font, but its name isn't readable, so I want to do what Wingdings did. Is it possible to define a setting in a TTF that is similar?

I am using FontForge.

Comment: Wingdings is tagged as a Symbol encoded font (just like, well, Symbol itself, and Webdings). This means that typing a letter such as "a" will *not* yield a useful graphic variant of `a`. Check what FontForge allows for encoding settings.

Comment: @usr2564301 Hmm. That's a decent hint. "The glyphs are in the MS Symbol area, so it's probably a symbol encoded font. One of those non-standard types." I also found some stuff in the documentation that may help, but I really don't know enough. https://fontforge.org/docs/techref/TrueOpenTables.html (search for "cmap" for character code mapping). Not sure if it's on the right track though.

Comment: Maybe this helps, too? [Symbol font](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/symbol) Code pages: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/os2#cpr

Answer (score 0):

There are separate settings for Font Name and Font Display name. I’m not actively using Fontforge but as far as I remember, it was in project settings.

Comment: I couldn't find anything